# Which .NET framework version will be included in Windows 7?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7, .net-framework-version

Does anybody know if Microsoft has already decided which **version of the .NET framework will be shipped in Windows 7** next year (2009)? Will it .NET 3.5 (SP 1) or maybe 4.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has issued a statement that there will be no other WinHEC before the next release of new Windows platform (Internet is abundant with information concerning this, [one site](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20081022/windows-7-targets-october-2009-rtm-retail-soon-after/)). On the other hand, from **Stephen Toub's**, **Somasegar's**, **ScottGu's** blogs (some of the driving forces behind the teams) etc. mention that .NET 4.0 Framework will be pushed out somewhat with Visual Studio 2010 early 2010.

I haven't found a confirmation on the parallels between Windows 7 and and .NET 4.0, but it seem to be that Windows 7 could be out slightly before .NET 4.0, albeit not necessarily much so. A quote from ScottGu's [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-beta-released.aspx) from mid-October tells

> I am going to try and post some more end-to-end tutorials in the coming weeks that show off how to use ASP.NET MVC from the beginning, and then logically progress to richer and richer scenarios.  Included in the list of tutorials will be my infamous AJAX with MVC post that I keep promising to write - but so far haven't (my excuse: the Silverlight 2, ASP.NET MVC, .NET 4.0, VS10, and Windows 7 ship cycles are all happening in parallel on my team - and I've unfortunately been really busy which is the reason for the delay)

Answer (score 2):

There are enough blog posts out there to know for sure that Visual Studio 2010 will be the development platform for .Net 4.0.  Since Windows normally ships just before VS we can assume it will have 3.5 installed.  Best part though is that the ship schedules have been hinted at having VS come out with-in the first few months of Windows shipping.  .Net 4.0 will not be in the box, but will be available very shortly afterwords.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows 7 Public Beta Released January 2009 has .net 3.5.  .net 4.0 is nt ready for beta test inclusion, however, some of the beta community have heard buz that net 4.0 will release to the RC1 version of Windows 7 in beta testing.

Comment: Thanks for keeping us up to date!

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, it depends on the release dates.

If Windows 7 is released before .NET 4.0 (which should be released with Visual Studio 2010), then it can not have .NET 4.0. But with .NET 3.5 is sure thing.

Answer (score 0):

The current latest release is .NET 3.5 SP1

I've read blogs about "the features in .NET 4" so I'm thinking if Microsoft wants to make a smart move, they'll release Windows 7 AFTER they release .NET 4

the again, this is windows we're talking about...