# .NET Framework at Windows 7

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, windows-7, built-in

What version of .NET Framework is built-in for Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[3.5 SP1 is pre-installed](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/07/22/windows-7-is-final-and-includes-net-3-5sp1.aspx)

If you run into any confusion, [this SF post has details](https://serverfault.com/questions/33521/install-net-3-5-sp1-on-windows-7-rc)

Answer (score 1):

It will be the .NET 3.5 version with SP1.
See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275808/which-net-framework-version-will-be-included-in-windows-7).

Comment: Will be? Windows 7 has been out for over a month at retail.

Comment: ehm yeah, meant to say something along the lines of 'That would be the (...)'. You are sharp today!